# Deploy issue with Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I am having trouble deploying files to my servers through the Release Pipelines.

I need to copy files to a Windows and a Linux server. I have tried using the file copy and the ssh file copy tasks, but they seem to be getting blocked because the microsoft servers aren't in my firewall whitelist. What is worse is that I can't seem to get a reliable list of IP's that I need to whitelist, and even if I did it seems they change over time.

So, any advice appreciated.

Also, I am a bit confused about the azure agent. My understanding was that you install them on the servers so that you don't need to worry about firewall issues. I just have the feeling I am missing something. I have no idea what that agent is doing at the moment - it certainly doesn't seem to be helping with the file deploy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Deploy issue with Azure Release Pipeline

Self-hosted agent: **An agent that you set up and manage on your own to run jobs is a self-hosted agent.**

To resolve this issue, you could create your private agent, then you can add the IP address of the machine where your private agent deployed to the firewall whitelist of your server machine.

In this case, Azure Release Pipeline runs on your private agent, and the IP of the machine where the private agent is located is added as a whitelist, so that it will not be blocked by the firewall of Windows and Linux servers.

You could refer the document [Self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) to create your private agent.